# how to trash a cached http 302 response

Tags: .htaccess, http, caching, browser

I had an old website that permanently redirected (HTTP 302) all traffic from  http://example.com/ to http://exmpale.com/drupal

now I re-implemented the entire website on wordpress but the old redirection is still cached on my user's browsers and breaking my revisiting users' experience (for some assets only).

I was thinking of adding to my new website a route serving as /drupal that will force the browser to trash the cache, is there a way to do so? maybe some http headers/javascript to trash the cache?

what do you think?

(BTW, I'm on a hosted service so my options are limited to php / .htaccess / javascript but I can't change http server configurations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said :

> permanently redirected (HTTP 302)

But it's either:

- temporary redirect (HTTP 302)
- permanent redirect (HTTP 301)

302 responses are usually not cached in browsers. If you were using 301 response code this could be stored until the user close the browser. If you have problems with your users it certainly means you were using 301, but if it is not the case it means something between you and the final user is storing a cache of the redirection (like a reverse proxy cache in front of your server?).

If you were using a 301 you might try to add a temporary redirect on `/drupal` to `/`. But this may create an inifinite redirection loop on the browsers. You can maybe prevent it by adding a fake argument on the redirection, like redirectiong to `/?redir=fix`.